# MVC 4 - I'd like to make a table visible or hidden based on a condition

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following MVC 4 Razor code:

```
<h4>You currently have @Model.Count() items listed for sale. @Html.ActionLink("Click here to add a new listing", "Create")</h4>
<br />

<table style="visibility: hidden">
....
```

I would like to make the visibility of the table hidden if @Model.Count() is zero and visible if the count is greater than zero. Is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the conditional operator to build the style:

```
<table style="visibility: @(Model.Count() == 0 ? "hidden" : "visible") ">
```

By the way you should use `Model.Any()` instead of the `Model.Count() == 0` check because it has better performance.

Or depending on your needs you can wrap your whole `table` inside an `if` so it won't be rendered at all and you won't send unnecessary data to the client:

```
@if(Model.Any())
{
    <table>
        ....
    </table>
}
```

Comment: @newesv - Thank you. And thanks for the heads up on Any. I should know better than that.